# Pydantic Version 2: Check for complex fields

Tags: python, pydantic

I would like to migrate from `pydantic` Version >1,<2 to Version >2. However, I cannot find a solution how to check for complex fields using the newest Version (currently V2.4.2)

Here is the code that worked with the "legacy" `pydantic`:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel
import typing as t


class ClassItems(BaseModel):
    item_id: str


class A(BaseModel):
    id: str
    items: t.List[ClassItems]


for i_field_name, i_field in A.model_fields.items():
    if i_field.is_complex():
        print(f"{i_field_name} is complex")
```

This returns now the error:

> AttributeError: 'FieldInfo' object has no attribute 'is_complex'